# Connecting to Maya through javascript

Tags: javascript, python, web-applications, maya

I am working on an app for sending commands to Maya, much like the iOS app [CameraMan](http://the3dninja.com/blog/?p=1223). However, I am looking for a way to make this web-based, rather than building a native app. I believe this can be done, but I'm stuck on how to make that initial connection. Maya creates a commandport that is accessible via a specific ip address:port number. I can send commands from Eclipse, for example, or even short python scripts. I've seen this in action in a native app, but how to do this through Javascript?

Maya does offer a browser plugin that does this, but of course it's a plugin and won't work on mobile browsers nor can I customize it for the exact application I'm trying to make.

By way of background, I have basic knowledge of Javascript, Python, and MEL scripting.

Update: I should specify that I'm not looking to control Maya over the internet. Rather, I'm looking for a way to make a connection over a local network, where I know the ip address, just like the CameraMan app I referenced above (just not as a native app).

Update 2: Unfortunately, this project is a bit of a no-go at this point. What I didn't realize was that in order to enable websockets on the Maya "server," I'd need to implement some third party libraries. Fine for individual use, but not if I'm trying to release a tool for other people.

Comment: In this example, is Maya running on the web server (one centralized location), or at the clients computer where the web page is being viewed?

Comment: Maya is running on a desktop connected to a local wireless network. The web-app is running on a mobile device also on the same wireless network.

Comment: Ergo Maya is running on a server, even a desktop can be a server. However this requires it to actually serve data. The problem is still the same as if it were a server in any case.

Comment: Oh and by the way local network in this case equals to internet. The server architecture of the world does not distinguish the difference same tubes how they are limited is your network admins job. For the app programmers perspective its all the same, especially since your browser can not do anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is possible, might not be practical or in this case the license of Autodesk might be a tiny problem. First lets define JavaScript a bit better, see JavaScript is a programming language and the web browser embedded JavaScript is bound by the browser. Its not a general thing about JavaScript, not all JavaScript runs in a browser. The JavaScript inside a web browser bound by the security rules of a browser and a browser can not in general communicate with the overall system just with the data inside the webpage and a server. So in order for java script in browser to talk to Maya you need a server connection.

Wrapping Maya as a web server is possible, I have done it in past with mel. Doing it with python would be easier. You can find existing demo code on [CreativeCrash](http://www.creativecrash.com/forums/mel/topics/online-control-of-maya-via-webpage#discussion_post_263927), tough its more of a proof of concept than anything else. There is not much you can do with the demo except introspect the open scene. Contrary to what some posts say the code should work as is. Its just hard to remotely debug peoples firewalls, as most firewall software will block the server unless otherwise stated, many users block entire Maya from the outside world with a override so be sure to check those things carefully.

Alternatively you can just take a existing java script telnet tool and telnet to a non filtered Maya command port and directly call mel/python inside Maya over that. Something like [anyterm](http://anyterm.org/index.html) would fit the bill. I've successfully used Maya with a phone ssh application before to fix a script error on a my vacation. This could be a easier attack vector if you need to just have programmatic access.

When you do something like this be sure you understand that there is a **big security problem** involved with this. Maya has full user access to the system, often full admin access. Maya can call everything on the computer at user level so nothing stops an attacker to take over the entire computer remotely.

*PS:* to be honest using a remote desktop or VNC over a private virtual network would probably be *much* better option.

Comment: This is a very interesting idea. I'm curious though if there's a way to avoid having to wrap Maya as a web server. If you don't need to do that when working locally (like sending commands from Eclipse) or from a an iOS device on the same local network (as in the CameraMan app), then is it possible to do the same through a simple web-app? I also like the idea of the javascript telnet tool, although I'll have to figure out how that could be automated to use the accelerometer data I'm collecting in the web-app. Also, I just learned the commandPort in Maya takes regular UTF-8 command strings.

Comment: No, any communication forma  browser form your browser is always a client server connection. Besides most maya scripting connections just send the data over a socket so same technology. Maya already knows how to serve stuff not just meaningful in web context. Of course On a local machine one has more IPC options. BUt over the network you don't have ANY other options except sockets.

Comment: Okay, just had the chance to try it this past weekend, and it's basically awesome. Now, two new questions/issues have come up. First, I'd like to use websockets, so I need to figure out how to set up the Maya "server" to do that. Second, I'd like to build the server in Python, but don't know how to get started on that.

Comment: https://github.com/theodox/standaloneRPC is a simple example of an HTTP-based Maya server intended to remote control Maya (typically a standalone).